# Cucumber.js Zombie.js Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, zombie.js

I've tried to find (google, stackoverflow etc) the solution by myself, but could not.

I'm working on Win7

Cucumber-js version: 0.4.0

Node version : v.0.10.26

Zombie@2.0.0-alpha31

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple.. let's go to the guardian signin page, and log in...But, when I'm visiting the website with Zombie I get this message:

Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined

If I'm trying to visit a simple html site, it is not happening.

What can I do to avoid this issue?

Code:

```
var assert = require("assert");
var myStepDefinitionsWrapper = function () {
  this.World = require("../support/world.js").World; 

  this.Given(/^I am on the Guardian site$/, function (callback) {
    this.browser.visit('https://id.theguardian.com/signin', callback);
    });
```

As you can see it is pretty simple, basic code, but the result is the following:

Zombie: Opened window https://id.theguardian.com/signin
Zombie: GET https://id.theguardian.com/signin => 200
.
.
.
.
.
Zombie: GET SOMETHING JS => 200
Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined
    Given I am on the Guardian site    # features\myFeature.feature:9
      RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    Then I should see "Guardian" title # features\myFeature.feature:10

(::) failed steps (::)

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Looks like an infinite recursive call either in Zombie, an underlying lib or the SUT (system under test). Is there any JS code on that signin page that could loop indefinitely?

Comment: Hey, yep it might be, but how could I ignore it?

Comment: First step would be to identify the cause. It might be a bug in the zombie/some lib and that should be fixed. If the problem comes from the SUT, then that should be fixed. 

If I get this right, zombie is running the SUT javascript code in the same process your tests are being run in. There's no way to prevent an infinite loop in the tested code to impact the tests when using Zombie (remeber: all in the same process). You might want to try something like selenium/webdriverjs if you want the tests to be *more detached* from the SUT.